# How To Save variables from a form after the submit? PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an initial form that submits data to another form, and then that form submits data to itself. The problem is that once that form submits data to itself, all the data submitted from the original form is lost. Is there a way to make sure the initial data is kept after the second form is updated? I know this is possible using SESSION, but is there another way of doing this? I have read a few people saying that it can be done utilizing hidden fields, but I have no idea how to do this. All I need is a simple example to see how its done.

Comment: If you are comfy with javascript. store it in your localstorage.

Comment: In the Second form keep a hidden field. On submission of first form assign form one data to this hidden field.

Comment: Did you try Local storage? `localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");` - To Read `localStorage.getItem("lastname");` To Remove the value `localStorage.removeItem("lastname");` Localstorage is the client based storage, no direct interaction with PHP

Comment: I have a hidden field on the second form, but how would I assign data from the first form to the second forms hidden field?

Comment: hidden fields are not the answer. suppose you want to move back and fix some value in the initial form. That data is lost if only you are relying on hidden fields.

Comment: if your form is doing POST then 

`<input type='hidden' name='firstformdata' value='<?php echo http_build_query($_POST); ?> '>`

[Official Doc http-build-query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Comment: If you care about the data, store it in the `Database` against the user session or guest user session `<?php echo session_id(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have this tag inside a `form`:

```
<input type="text" name="foo">
```

You enter some value there and you will be able to reach it on server-side with `$_POST["foo"]`. Now, let's suppose you have another `form` of the response of the target page. You can include this value like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["foo"]) ? $_POST["foo"] : ""; ?>"
```

Here you check whether the given value was posted and if so, the posted value will be the value of the `input`. If not, the `input`'s value will be empty string. When you post the `form` containing this `hidden` `input`, the `value` will be posted as well.

As you have already mentioned, another way of doing this is to store the value in `$_SESSION` and reuse it. Also, you may store the value in a database and load it.

Comment: I see how hidden fields are used, but my problem is that once the form is submitted the older data is forgotten. Is there a way to keep the original data along with the new data that is being entered into the form without using SESSION?